# Method Help in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods

I've been following along with a book that my boss advised I use, Agile Web Development With Rails 4.

This excerpt from the book is throwing me for a loop as to how to accomplish what it's asking:

---

Methods

Let’s write a method that returns a cheery, personalized greeting. We’ll invoke
that method a couple of times.

```
def say_goodnight(name)
  result = 'Good night, ' + name
  return result
end
```

# Time for bed...

```
puts say_goodnight('Mary-Ellen') # => 'Goodnight, Mary-Ellen'

puts say_goodnight('John-Boy') # => 'Goodnight, John-Boy'
```

Having defined the method, we call it twice. In both cases, we pass the result
to the method `puts()`, which outputs to the console its argument followed by a
newline (moving on to the next line of output).
You don’t need a semicolon at the end of a statement as long as you put each
statement on a separate line. Ruby comments start with a # character and
run to the end of the line. Indentation is not significant (but two-character
indentation is the de facto Ruby standard).
Ruby doesn’t use braces to delimit the bodies of compound statements and
definitions (such as methods and classes). Instead, you simply finish the body
with the keyword end. The keyword return is optional, and if not present, the
results of the last expression evaluated will be returned.

---

First off, with this particular method, would you be defining it in the controller or model? As well, what would be the exact means of calling the method in the view? I've tried a number of different ways and always seem to end up at an error screen that says:

> ArgumentError in SayController#say_goodnight
>
> wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at your error log:

```
ArgumentError in SayController#say_goodnight

wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

This means that in your class `SayController`, method `say_goodnight` you have not provided the require number of arguments. This means somewhere in your code you have:

```
say_goodnight()
```

instead of

```
say_goodnight(name)
```

I can't quite tell if your book is only trying to teach you about Ruby methods, or also talking about Ruby on Rails MVC (model, view, controller) architecture. I'm assuming its the first. If you are writing a Rails App, it would also help to include the respective Model, View, and Controller code you are working with.

Comment: I can't find any instance where I have say_goodnight(). However, when I'm trying to call the code, I've been using something along the lines of <%= say_goodnight('Kyle').

The original code in the controller reads as it is written in the book:

def say_goodnight(name)
result = 'Good night, ' + name
return result
end.

Does the original code need to be say_goodnight('name')?

Comment: @K.Davis try seeing if you have mentioned `say_goodnight` without the parenthesis in your code somewhere.

Comment: @K.Davis your original code looks fine from what I can see. You can usually follow the stack trace from your Rails debug logs and see the line of code at fault. Could you include that as well?

Comment: ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):

app/controllers/say_controller.rb:9:in `say_goodnight'
Started GET "/say/say_goodnight" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-14 14:18:10 -0500
Processing by SayController#say_goodnight as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms



ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):

app/controllers/say_controller.rb:9:in `say_goodnight'

Comment: I apologize, I'm still fairly, fairly new, so I'm not certain how to get that data for you. This is what command prompt is telling me as I try to go to this view.

Comment: @K.Davis No worries, we all start somewhere. See here `app/controllers/say_controller.rb:9` can you include what is in line 9 of the `say_controller.rb` file?

Comment: It's referring to the beginning of the code, def say_goodnight(name).

The full code is the same one I copied from the book that it wants you to pull from:
  def goodnight(name)
  result = 'Good night, ' + name
  return result
  end

Comment: The thing the section doesn't really explain is... Do you put the code in the Model, or do you include the code in the Controller? I know it calls it a method, whereas I've been told an action is what you usually include in the controller.

Comment: Hm, are there any more error logs? If I were you, I would even try to run the command from terminal `grep -r say_goodnight app/*` from your RailsApp root directory. That would list all mentions of that method in all your files.

Comment: MVC can be hard to wrap around your head in the beginning.  To be quite frank, the way you are trying to invoke say_goodbye() from your View, it might be best to put it in your Helpers `app/helpers/`

Comment: Well, I've put the code in the say_helper.rb file. This has allowed me to load the view successfully, but it won't display what I need it to. Once you've established the method. What would be the code to pull it? I've tried <%= say_goodnight('Kyle') %>, but that doesn't work. At this point, I may just move on, because this is more of an example from the book, rather than a step in the creation of a project. It's just very frustrating to encounter this roadblock.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help, @mhz. From speaking with my boss more, it looks like the code in question is expected to be entered into IRB. Which makes some sense considering the section is about Ruby, but it makes no mention of it, essentially glossing over a lot of info to give you a broad idea of Ruby.

Comment: I appreciate it!